# convert word characters to other characters in python

Tags: python

this program outputs a user's name in the symbols as given below. instead of typing all letters in * s. how can i create a program that will take in A and print in terms of *s without this lengthy typing

```
   def patt(name):
        length = len(name)

        for i in range(0,length):
            n = name[i]

            if n == 'A':

             print("""
                      ***
                     *   *
                    *******
                   **     **    """)
            elif n == 'B':
              print("""
                    ******
                    *     *
                    ******
                    *     *
                    *******
                           """)
            elif n == 'C':
                print("""
                    *******
                    *
                    *
                    *
                    *******
    """)
            elif n == 'D':
                 print("""
                    *******
                    *      *
                    *      *
                    *      *
                    *******

    """)
            elif n == 'E':

                 # etc


    def main():
        name = input("please enter your name: ")
        patt(name)

    main()
```

Comment: You may want to look into [dictionaries](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/)

Comment: yes, but i still need to type the whole thing right?

Comment: It will still need the letters, but you can at least minify the program a little bit (use `\n` for new lines, and `\t` to replace spaces where possible)

Comment: Do you mean writing a detected letter by a loop?

Comment: yes - kaan bobac

Answer (score 1):

Use the banner program on Linux to covert any string to the pattern
with #s.

```
$ banner P
######
#     #
#     #
######
#
#
#
```

Comment: How would you do this with Python?

Comment: You run it in a shell, and cut-and-paste the string into python.  I would simply have a dictionary say mypatts, and so something like:
mypatts['P'] = '''<cut-and-paste-the-output-of-banner-P>'''

Comment: can you give a detailed description about the banner program?

Comment: It's a pretty common program on any Unix/Linux platform.  On ubuntu you can do an 'apt-get install sysvbanner' to install the banner program.

Comment: sorry, not sure about windows.  May be you can find something online for windows.